# Convert rows in columns with informix query

Tags: sql, informix

I want to convert

```
inpvacart       inpvapvta inpvapvt1 inpvapvt2 inpvapvt3 inpvapvt4
CS-279          270.4149    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000   0.0000
AAA5030         1.9300      1.9300    1.6212    0.0000   0.0000
```

Query

```
select  
    inpvacart, 
    inpvapvta, 
    inpvapvt1, 
    inpvapvt2, 
    inpvapvt3, 
    inpvapvt4
from inpva;
```

into this

```
  inpvacart   line  value
  CS-279       1    270.4149
  CS-279       2    0.00000
  CS-279       3    0.00000
  CS-279       4    0.00000
  CS-279       5    0.00000
  AAA5030      1    1.9300
  AAA5030      2    1.9300
  AAA5030      3    1.6212    
  AAA5030      4    0.0000
  AAA5030      5    0.0000
```

I have tried this

```
 select s.inpvacart,l.lista,l.resultados
 from inpva as s,
table(values(1,s.inpvapvta),
            (2,s.inpvapvt1),
            (3,s.inpvapvt2),
            (4,s.inpvapvt3),
            (5,s.inpvapvt4))
)as l(lista,resultados);
```

But it does not work in informix 9

Is there a way to transpose rows to columns?

Thank You

Comment: What are you doing with Informix 9.x?  It should have been put out to pasture a long time ago.  Versions 10 and 11.10 are also obsolete; version 11.50 is out of marketing (so you can't buy it unless you already have it).  11.70 is the 'old' version and 12.10 is the current version.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't know Informix so my answer was generic sql, but can you tell me if there is a better way to do this in Informix? Maybe there is some unpivot/transpose thing?

Comment: @jpw: Your answer is spot on.  It saved me having to type the same thing, so thank you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good to know, cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Informix has any `unpivot` operator to transpose columns to rows like for instance MSSQL does, but one way to do this is to transpose the columns manually and then use `union` to create a single set like this:

```
select inpvacart, 1 as line, inpvapvta as value from inpva
union all
select inpvacart, 2 as line, inpvapvt1 as value from inpva
union all
select inpvacart, 3 as line, inpvapvt2 as value from inpva
union all
select inpvacart, 4 as line, inpvapvt3 as value from inpva
union all
select inpvacart, 5 as line, inpvapvt4 as value from inpva
order by inpvacart, line;
```

It's not very pretty but it should work.