# I need to perform a pivot from horizon to vertical in informix SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, transpose, informix

I have a table that has year in the row and month in the column linked to a job code. i need to create a table that will have job code in one column, date in the other and then value in the 3rd.

The current table looks like below:

| job_code | cost_budget_year | jul | aug | sep | oct | nov | dec | jan | feb | mar | apr | may | jun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Job1 | 2022 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 118439.21 | 777723.08 | 1435763.26 |
| Job1 | 2023 | 2232943.95 | 914327.20 | 100043.83 | 574206.50 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |

I would usually do this using a pivot in sql server etc, but the data is stored in an INFORMIX server that needs to be queried using a JDBC driver etc.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

I tired to use the pivot functionality but i think pure sql will be needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert rows in columns with informix query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385073/convert-rows-in-columns-with-informix-query)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.